# Why does C bother to provide type definitions?

Tags: c, typedef, preprocessor

I have come across the following problem, and I could not find any specific explanations as to: Why does C bother to provide type definitions ? Isn't defining BOOL macro just as good as defining Bool type using `typedef`?

For example, `#define` directive can be used to create a macro that could be used as a Boolean type:

```
#define Bool int
```

There's another way to set up a Boolean type, using a feature known as type definition.

```
typedef int Bool;
```

Why is the last method preferred? What are the advantages?

Comment: There is no `BOOL` macro in C, nor a built-in `bool` type. There is, however a boolena type `_Bool` which should be used instead of homebrew `typedef`s or macros. Re your question: this is **not** preferred and strongly discouraged.

Comment: Note that C's `_Bool` is a type different from the result of OP's `typedef int Bool ;` in many functionally attributes.  `Bool` here is not a good example to demonstrate OP's `typedef` vs. `#define` concerns.

Comment: @chux: Siple example where they differ: `_Bool b = 5; printf(%d", b);`. Try this with a `typedef`ed `int`.

Comment: _Bool is potentially a bad example because it's a builtin with semantics that aren't achievable with a typedef.

Comment: @Olaf, my concern was/is why isn't defining a BOOL macro just as good as defining a Bool type using typedef, just as the question states. I do not understand why it is unclear as I have stated my concerns in the question. As pointed out, however, it seems that I have used a bad example by using Bool.

Comment: @Rizzo: For a boolean type, both are wrong, because you just can't. For the others, your question seems to boil down to "what's the difference between macros and declarations?". It is not really related to `typedef` nor other constructs actually.

Comment: @Rizzo C has a real _Bool. It's different from any other integer type in that that any nonzero value stored into it is stored as one and zeros stored into it are stored as zeros. You can't get that with a typedef (overflows and narrowing truncations get in the way). That's what probably ticks nitpickers off about your question (which is, otherwise, a very good question, IMO).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from the above mentioned reasons, one more thing, a MACRO can be undefined and redefined, but not a `typedef`. So, from one perspective, a `typedef` is more *definitive*.

For example

```
#define MAX 5

//some use of MAX

#undef MAX
#define MAX 10

// some more use of MAX
```

is perfectly valid, but an attempt to do something like

```
typedef int into;

///something....

typedef char into;
```

is invalid, as the "type" is already defined previously.

So, `typedef`, which creates an alias to a "type", is considered much more consistent, in that regard.

Comment: *"So, from one perspective, a typedef is more definitive."* - This is the best thing I heard today :) I'd upvote twice if I could, just for that. Just don't ask me why I like it so much, because I have no idea

Comment: @StoryTeller Twice is not a good option, go for thrice. :P

Answer (score 10):

There are two important differences between type definitions and macro definitions.

Type definitions are more powerful than macro definitions. In particular, *array and pointer types can't be defined as macros.* Suppose that we try to use a macro to define a "pointer to integer" type:

```
  #define PTR_TO_INT int *
```

The declaration

```
  PTR_TO_INT p, q, r
```

will become

```
  int * p, q, r
```

after preprocessing. Unfortunately, **only** `p` is a pointer; `q` and `r` are ordinary **integer variables.** Type definitions don't have this problem.

Second, `typedef` names are subject to the same scope rules as variables; a `typedef` name defined inside a function body wouldn't be recognized outside the function. Macro names, on the other hand, are replaced by the preprocessor wherever they appear.

Comment: Object-pointers should never be `typedef`ed anyway. And arrays only if well thought.

Comment: A weakness here is that a problems of `#define PTR_TO_INT int *` is discussed, yet a solution using `typedef` is not shown` - IOWs, a one sided argument. `typdef  int * ptr_to_int;` is not a winning solution ether.

Comment: @chux "`typdef int * ptr_to_int;` is not a winning solution ether." It certainly wins over `#define PTR_TO_INT int *`.  In such a situation, I fail to see what's wrong with `typedef`.  `typedef` certainly makes  complex definitions and declarations such as function pointers in structures that take functions as arguments a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  `#define PTR_TO_INT int *` is a [paper tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_tiger)  Of course some `typdef` is better than `#define PTR_TO_INT int *`, yet this answer still lacks a specific example of how to use `typedef` in that case and how that is good.

Comment: @chux, why would something like this not be considered good practice, or a "winning solution" ? `typedef int* IntPtr ; IntPtr x, y, z;`

Comment: The semantics of C are too readily confused when an object is mistaken between an object and an object pointer. `IntPtr x` gains little over `int *x;`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers cover more details.